# Spring wont deserialize Object when content is Application/JSON

Tags: java, spring

I am try to create an endpoint in spring where I sent raw JSON and it will not deserialize to object but if I use form Data it works fine. I am just wondering what I did wrong?

this is the object

```
    @Document("Boats")
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
public class Boat{
    @Id
    private String id;
    private Boolean online;
    private String boatName;
    private String lastOnline;

    private String password;
    @JsonIgnore
    @Transient
    private java.net.InetAddress inetAddress;
    private String displayAddress;
    private String displayStatus;

    public Boat(String boatName, InetAddress inetAddress,Boolean online) {
        this.online = online;
        this.boatName = boatName;
        this.inetAddress = inetAddress;
        this.displayAddress = inetAddress.getHostAddress();
        if(online){
            String pattern = "E, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z";
            SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);
            simpleDateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("CST"));
            this.lastOnline = simpleDateFormat.format(new Date());
        }
        updateDisplayStatus();
    }
    public void updateDisplayStatus(){
        if(getOnline()){
            setDisplayStatus(BoatStatus.ONLINE.getDisplayText());
        }else{
            setDisplayStatus(BoatStatus.OFFLINE.getDisplayText());
        }
    }
}
```

and this is the endpoint

```
    @PostMapping(path= "/boat/update")
    public ResponseEntity updateBoat(@RequestBody Boat boat){
        boatFacade.updateBoat(boat);
        return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
    }
```

this is the body of the request

```
{
"id":"62ca4f7c5a3e0f1411445065",
"online":"false",
"boatName":"dfsjkdfsd",
"lastOnline":"null",
"password":"null",
"displayAddress":"10.50.50.50",
"displayStatus":"ONLINE"
}
```

these are the POM dependencies I am using not sure if I am missing
a dependency

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>31.1-jre</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Comment: What does the request body you're sending up look like? Can you show the error you're getting?

Comment: there are no errors in the logs at all

Comment: How do you know it's not serializing? I would use a debugger and  set a breakpoint at the start of the endpoint to get some more information, because you should definitely be getting an error somewhere if something went wrong

Comment: I did and its showing nothing, all nulls in the object if I use form data it works fine

Comment: Well I setup a new project excluding mongo and it should work out of the box as you have it. So I'm curious as to  how exactly the request looks when you're sending it up? Are you using postman? If you are make sure the dropdown on the raw tab is JSON not TEXT as default

Comment: I think you are missing content type while making the request. Can you share the curl request?

Comment: I am using postman with a request body of raw, type JSON and in the headers the only thing I add is content-type but it dosent seem to make any difference

Comment: curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:8080/boat-service/boat/update' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
    "id": "62ca4f7c5a3e0f1411445065",
    "online": "false",
    "boatName": "kjdklasd",
    "lastOnline": "null",
    "password": "null",
    "displayAddress": "10.20.36.38",
    "displayStatus": "ONLINE"
}'

Comment: try changing the online field in your request json to boolean type : "online":"false" -> "online" : false

Comment: yeah I had that, tried it again changing it back didnt work. I thought maybe it was the boolean causing the issue

Comment: avoid business on constructors. Did you try a custom mapper?

Answer (score -1):

It is always recommended to specify the Type/Kind of data that your endpoint consume/produce.

```
@PostMapping(value = "/boat/update", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
```

[Object reserializes - debug Point](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2hHBl.png)

[PostMan Setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3biXk.png)

Comment: tried this, dosent work either

Comment: I have added few screen shots to the answer, take a look.

Comment: could it be a dependency I missed? how did you setup the project?

Comment: I don't think its a dependency problem. Retry from Google Chrome Postman Plugin once : https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop

Comment: I tried from chrome, didnt work, maybe I should try remaking the spring app. should I use spring intiliazer?